# Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> NameError: name 'swim' is not defined

Tags: python, module, nameerror

what does this mean? I'm a beginner and I can't figure it out, because "swim"part is written identically to "left" part and for some reason it doesn't work. I can't spot the mistake, could you help me?

I thought that maybe it's some sort of mistake with the tabs, but I adjusted them and it still doesn't work.

```
crossroad = input("You are on a crossroad, where do you want to go? Do you want to turn left, turn right or maybe go straight ahead? type 'left', 'right' or 'go ahead'\n" )

if crossroad == "left":

  left = print("You are now by the lake. Do you want to swim across or wait for a boat? type 'swim' or 'wait'")

  if left == "swim":

    print("You noticed a mysterious chest in the water. Do you want to dive or continue swimming?         type 'dive' or 'continue'\n")




Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'swim' is not defined
```

Comment: Should't that be `left = input(...`?

Comment: I ran your code with a slight difference of substituting the first line by `crossroad = "left"` and I saw no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're getting a name error, but you should be using input rather than print on line 3.

Comment: Thanks:) Yes, the problem was that I used print, when I changed it to input it worked.